# ListAdapter's items aren't refreshed if RecyclerView has hidden visibility

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I have a `ListAdapter` implementation of a very basic title-subtitle info items. When I update items or clear the list using `submitList(items)`, the changes are applied and everything works normally.

But, if the `RecyclerView` is hidden, `ListAdapter` refreshes the items only when I make `RecyclerView` visible again. This causes a half-second blink between old and new items.

Here's a pseudo-code version<sup>1</sup> of what I am doing:

```
suspend fun fetchItems() {
  adapter.submitList(null)
  showLoadingIndicator(); hideRecyclerView() // View.GONE

  val result = api.fetchItems() // coroutine
  adapter.submitList(result.items)
  hideLoadingIndicator(); showRecyclerView()
}
```

If I don't update RecyclerView's visibility, there's no blink or transition between items. I can see that the items are cleared and then, after some time, they are shown.

If I hide RecyclerView for the duration of API call, it feels like `adapter.submitList(null)` didn't work. When API returns result, old data is shown for half a second, then gets switched with the data from the API.

Why is this happening? I guess it might be a performance improvement to not update `View`s when they are `View.GONE`.

How can I make it so that it doesn't blink like that?

<sup>1</sup> I am using `LiveData` and MVVM to update UI and `ListAdapter`.

Comment: Are you using stable IDs? Does your listadapters itemcallback include diff payload?

Comment: Isn't this an expected behaviour of recyclerviews' nature? If there is no item views then there is nothing to bind. This how recyclerview works, doesn't it?

Comment: What if you try `VIEW.INVISIBLE` instead?

Comment: @zaitsman `View.INVISIBLE` behaves normally, that's why edited it out of the question. But, I am curious about `View.GONE`, and I want to know if such a behavior is documented or not.

Comment: @Pawel No, no stable IDs or payloads. Just item identity and content comparisons.

Comment: Tbh it kind of makes sense as a performance optimisation on the framework part. Since `INVISIBLE` behaves as you want i'd just use that.

Comment: When view is invisible it's still laid out but not drawn. When view is GONE it's not laid out. Recyclerview by design needs to know its size to bind enough views to fill its bounds. Submit list runs asyncdiffer and you immediately make view gone so to me it looks like there's no layout phase to execute that'd clear out whatever was left from previous list. Try running `adapter.notifydatasetchanged` just before you submit result items, maybe that will help since it forcefully discards all viewholders.